# How can I fetch and merge updates to a bare repo using "git" gem in ruby

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm using a ruby gem called "git"(https://rubygems.org/gems/git) to deal with git repositories. I first clone the repository into a bare one on my local machine but I can't seem to pull updates as this is only a bare repository.
I can only use g.fetch to fetch the updates. I know the updates are fetched but I need them to be merged so that when I use g.log it shows the latest commits. I know that I should use

```
    git fetch origin master:master
```

if I want to do it from a terminal but what if I want to do it using ruby's gem "git"?
I tried using g.merge but it says that this needs a working tree.

EDIT: What I need is to fetch updates from the remote origin repository to be in my local bare repository.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not the answer your looking for, but this is super easy to accomplish with normal git...

1. Create a new git repository.
2. Navigate to the local repository you want to clone in your terminal and type:

   ```
     `git push -f new-git-url master:master`
   ```

   This will push your local files to your new repo.
3. Clone your new repository.

Comment: Thanks for answering but as I said, I know how to do it in terminal(with normal git). Anyways, your answer makes me doubt that I made what I wanted clear... What I need is to get changes from a remote repository to my local bare one.